# GUI for my auto installer keeps going blank

Tags: powershell, installation, automation

I am currently working on an auto installer for newly configured computers where I work.  It has a GUI which allows you to choose which programs will be installed.  When the file paths are correct the GUI is blank but when I purposefully mess up the file paths the checkboxes will pop back up.

Sorry if this seems like a very dumb question.  I am extremely new to this and have gotten a lot of help from various different websites. This is basically me working off of another auto installer script that I found on this website.

```
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()


$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,700)
$Form.text ="Software Installer"

############################################## Start group boxes

$groupBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
$groupBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (10,20)
$groupBox.text = "Available Software to Install:" 
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox)


$Checkboxes += New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
$Checkboxes = New-Object System.Drawing.Size (10,20)

$Button1                         = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "Install"
$Button1.width                   = 100
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(245,585)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'



$apps = [PSCustomObject]@{

    Name = ''

    Path = ''

    PreTransfer = ''



}


$apps = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\Zach\Desktop\Installers\appslist.csv


$groupBox.Controls.Add($Button1)

$Checkboxes = @()
$y = 20
foreach ($a in $apps)
{
    $Checkbox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
    $Checkbox.name = $a.Name
    $Checkbox.Text = $a.Name
    $Checkbox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,$y)
    $y += 30
    $groupBox.Controls.Add($Checkbox)

    $Checkboxes += $Checkbox

}


$groupbox.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(564,(624*$checkboxes.Count))


#to look at each box
$Button1.Add_Click({
    foreach ($i in $Checkboxes){
    if ($i.checked -eq $true) {
    Start-Process $i.AccessibleDescription
    }
}
 })


$form.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Have you stepped through the code to see where variables or code isn't what you think it is?

Comment: Yes.  I've combed through it all, i'm stumped.  I don't receive any errors when I run it either.  I suspect there may be something in there that isn't correct that is just beyond my knowledge.

Comment: But have you actually debugged it?  Have you run the script in the debugger and stepped through each line to verify that the values in the variables are what you expect?  What does your CSV look like?

Comment: I figured it out.  My CSV was setup very wrong.  Thank you for having me check it again!